# How to debug docker-compose? Where are config paths set?

Tags: docker, go, debugging, docker-compose, goland

I am trying to debug `docker-compose`, i.e. [this Go file](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/main.go), to work on some issue ([this one](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10043)). To do that, I have set up a GoLang debugger

The output of `go run main.go -f /.../project_root/docker-compose.yml -f /.../project_root/folder1/docker-compose.yml config` is as expected, the merged config files.

For some reason, I can not find the config files being set in the code, although they must be set somewhere as the output is the correctly merged config files. I suspected they must be set somewhere around [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/cli.go#L500) or [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go#L131). But in the former place, the value of `cli.configFile` is `nil`, and in the latter place, the value of `o.ConfigPaths` is `nil`.

So I have two questions:

1. Where are the config files being set? and
2. (if 1 cannot be answered) What am I doing wrong in trying to emulate the behavior of the actual `docker-compose` command?

#### Edit

In accordance to the above mentioned issue and having found where the config paths are probably set, my question now is where the volume paths are being set.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go#L50  This might actually be the place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which config paths? The path for the default configuration file (`docker-compose.yaml`) is set by the `cli.WithDefaultConfigPath` method (in the [`compose-go`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/cli/options.go) repository). The possible names for the default config are set [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/cli/options.go#L303):

```
// DefaultFileNames defines the Compose file names for auto-discovery (in order of preference)
var DefaultFileNames = []string{"compose.yaml", "compose.yml", "docker-compose.yml", "docker-compose.yaml"}
```

The `WithDefaultConfigPath` method iterates over this list, and if it finds a matching file, it gets applied to the `ConfigPaths` field in the `ProjectOptions` struct, [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go#L93):

```
type ProjectOptions struct {
    ProjectName   string
    Profiles      []string
    ConfigPaths   []string
    WorkDir       string
    ProjectDir    string
    EnvFile       string
    Compatibility bool
}
```

The `WithDefaultConfigPath` method is applied in the `toProjectOptions` method, [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go#L224):

```
func (o *ProjectOptions) toProjectOptions(po ...cli.ProjectOptionsFn) (*cli.ProjectOptions, error) {
    return cli.NewProjectOptions(o.ConfigPaths,
        append(po,
            cli.WithWorkingDirectory(o.ProjectDir),
            cli.WithOsEnv,
            cli.WithEnvFile(o.EnvFile),
            cli.WithDotEnv,
            cli.WithConfigFileEnv,
            cli.WithDefaultConfigPath,
            cli.WithName(o.ProjectName))...)
}
```

Comment: I guess this has to understood as some kind of prerun, where the config files are only set in the default case (when there is no `-f` flag), right?

Comment: I am now trying to find where the volume paths are set inside the actual resulting config when specifying multiple `-f` flags with relative paths.

Comment: Right, if you provide that `-f` option, that populates the `ConfigPaths` field directly, so there's no need to set a default.